# Why is Rspec/Capybara giving me a expected css ... to return something error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

The test I am using is:

```
it { should have_link('Logout', href: logout_url) }
```

I am just testing for the existence of a `<a>` tag with `Logout` as the text, and the href to be `logout_url` path.  Should I be using another syntax for this?

Gems:

```
rails 3.2.6
rspec-rails 2.10.1
capybara 1.1.2
```

Comment: We might need more complete code and the error output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can do this. I'd recommend (if you haven't already) familiarizing yourself with the overall [capybara dsl](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master) as well as some of the specific sections such as the [capybara matchers](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers).

I believe your test is fine written as:

```
it { should have_link('Logout', href: logout_url) }
```

as long as the link text really is 'Logout' and the href is specified correctly (see below).

According to the [capybara docs](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_link?-instance_method), the first parameter to `have_link` is what's called the `locator`. In your case it's 'Logout'. This can be either the text in the link itself, or it can be the #id of the dom element. So in your case you need to have the text 'Logout' in the link that has the `logout_url` link.

Note that locaters in capybara are *case sensitive*, so make sure you match on case.

You might also want to consider whether you should be using `logout_url` and not `logout_path`. By default, rails doesn't always generate the full url for most links. It just generates paths. Here's the difference:

```
users_url: http://localhost/users
users_path: /users
```

Check your page to see which of these types of url's are being generated by your app.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it should be logout_path.

Also you can try to use save_and_open_page to understand what's going wrong.